# Use PDO connection with my own class

Tags: php, pdo

I can't use the PDO class methods from my own `pdo_connection` class, with or without `extends PDO`, it doesn't work properly.

```
Class pdo_connection { 
//connection create 
    private $dbhost = "127.0.0.1"; 
    private $dbname = "db"; 
    private $dbuser = "user"; 
    private $dbpass = "pass"; 
    public function __construct() { 
        return $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass); 
    } 
}
```

And then when I create the object:

```
require("api/pdo.connection.class.php"); 
$db = new pdo_connection(); 
$db->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
```

I can't use exec, because is not a method of pdo_connection class, but I want to use the methods of PDO that is created in the `pdo_connection` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `pdo_connection` like that, you will have to extend PDO.

Example:

```
class db extends PDO {
```

Then, inside that class, in `__construct`, use `parent::__construct`:

```
parent::__construct('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
```

---

This is the class that I made that uses that method: **[[link]](http://pastie.org/5495623)**

Usage:

```
include_once 'db.php';
$db = new db('user');
// Do stuff with $db
```

Comment: class posted by op does not extend PDO

Answer (score 3):

The return type of any constructor should be `void`.  You use the constructor to initialize object properties.  The return value when you call `new ClassName()` will be of type `ClassName`.

That being said, if you want to extend class `PDO` you can do so this way:

`class pdo_connection extends PDO { ... }`

However, personally I wouldn't go about it this way.  In fact, quickly searching led me to this article:

- [Extending PDO a waste… (22 Sep 2005; by Davey Shafik)](http://daveyshafik.com/archives/96-extending-pdo-a-waste.html)

Bear in mind I've never personally *tried* to extend PDO, so take that in consideration.

Instead, why not store the PDO object as a class property, then define your own functions that interact with that PDO Object?

```
Class pdo_connection { 
//connection create 
    private $dbhost = "127.0.0.1"; 
    private $dbname = "db"; 
    private $dbuser = "user"; 
    private $dbpass = "pass"; 
    public function __construct() { 
        try { // Don't forget this....
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass); 
        } catch(PDOException $e) { }
    } 

    public function exec() {
     /// do your exec stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: That linked article contains some, er, *dubious* statements and information, but the general idea of this is OK - please note the you would need to call `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` to make PDO throw exceptions instead of triggering errors in any subsequent activity (after the constructor), and it is highly recommended (if not essential) that you call `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE)` when working with MySQL.

Comment: The linked article is really old, some context: http://www.phpdeveloper.org/news/3913 - Please check your sources when you drive conclusions from them.

Answer (score 3):

1. Follow naming/autoloading convention e.g. [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).
2. Use Autoloader, if you are using require/include for your classes, you are doing it wrong, most likely.
3. It is not enough to wrap code in `class` and call it OOP.
4. I see no reason why you couldn't extend PDO, but anyways...

```
class MyPdo
{

  protected $db;
  protected $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
  protected $dbname = 'db';
  protected $dbuser = 'user';
  protected $dbpass = 'pass';

  protected function __construct()
  {
    $this->db = PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
  }

  public function __call($method, $args)
  {
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->db, $method), $args);
  }

}
```